# How do I make a Label with two containers. One smaller and another bigger

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do this design [image: design]

Which widget should I use to approach this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tags and they are overlapped.

So you can use "Stack" to build it:

```
 Widget _buildCustomTag() {
      Radius radius = Radius.circular(6);
      return Container(
        height: 60, 
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4), // this is just for checking the view
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
                child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(topRight: radius, bottomRight: radius)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text('R\$ 99,90'),
            )),
            Positioned(
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: radius, bottomRight: radius)),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 20),
                  child: Text('05/01/2021'),
                )),
          ],
        ));
     }
```

[image: Layout screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expanded widget and adding its flex width value.

```
  Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Container(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Expanded or Flexible widget for that use below code :

```
       Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text(
                    '05/01/2021',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: 45,
                  child: Text(
                    'R\$ 99,90',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Your screen look like -> [image]

Comment: with this solution, we have a little `white pixels` after `red label`